# I'm unable to access 'https://github.com/Danniecodjoe/alx-system_engineering-devops.git/':

Tags: c#, .net, passwords, wsl-2, git-push

The TLS connection was non-properly terminated. What do i do? And I'm unable to push my files to git.

I tried to git push. I entered my github username and password, Authentication failed. I also used my fine classic token and now I got this response "fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/Danniecodjoe/alx-system_engineering-devops.git/': GnuTLS recv error (-110): The TLS connection was non-properly terminated."

how do I push my files successfully?